# Integrate Facebook Page Plugin in website

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I'm trying to integrate the Facebook page plugin for my website, but the change of API occurred on April 30 is giving me problems and i find no updated guide.

when I go to generate the code I am told:

Include the JavaScript SDK on your page once, ideally right after the opening  tag.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Place the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page.

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Grifo-
Imports/579559248856812?fref=ts" data-width="300" data-height="200" 
data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-
posts="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote 
cite="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Grifo-Imports
/579559248856812?fref=ts"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Grifo-
Imports/579559248856812?fref=ts">Grifo Imports</a></blockquote></div>
</div>
```

and I'm going to enter the code in the web page in this way

```
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div id="pageHeader">
    <img class="logo" src="GrifoImports_Logo_FINAL_Reverse-web-200.png"/>

        <ul id="menu">
            <li id="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Were to buy us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
   </div>

   <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Grifo-
   Imports/579559248856812?fref=ts" data-width="300" data-height="200" 
   data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-
   posts="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote 
   cite="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Grifo-Imports
   /579559248856812?fref=ts"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages
   /Grifo-Imports/579559248856812?fref=ts">Grifo Imports</a></blockquote>
   </div></div>

   <div id="container">
   <div id="slideshow">
   <img style="display: none; opacity: -0.01;" src="wine/01.JPG">
   <img style="display: block; opacity: 0.54;" src="wine/02.JPG">
   <img style="display: block; opacity: 0.54;" src="wine/03.JPG">
   <img style="display: block; opacity: -0.01;" src="wine/04.JPG">
   </div>

   </div>
```

but in the website does not appear the Page Plugin. Where am I doing wrong ???

Thanks to those who will respond... and sorry for my imperfect english! ;)

Comment: You do not really have whitespace in those attribute values in your actual code, right? What does the browser console say?

Comment: That all looks fine - I'd second CBroe - are there any messages in your console? Could you try putting the code within a container?

Comment: try  this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/32134145/1956964